# Understandability of a phrase

Tags: tenses

I am not sure whether to post this to English Learners SE instead, so if the question seems too easy or too silly feel free to migrate it.

So, I have a sentence: "Life is going to haven't made sense sometime".

What I am trying to say is: "sometime, there will be a moment, when you realise that life has never made any sense". I feel like the first version is more concise, and still follows the rules of English grammar, but I'm unsure if it's understandable.

So, is the first 'condensed' version correct and/or understandable? If no, can you think of any alternative to 'condense' the second? 
Thank you.

Comment: It's only understandable after you think about it a bit, it's not easily parsed.

Comment: Also, _once_ is usually used to refer to the past (like "once upon a time" in fairy tales). To refer to the future, we usually use *sometime*.

Comment: _had sense_ should be _made sense_.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Good to know someone understands it, even if the sentence seems unusable in the real world. Too bad: I love so much this power to combine different grammatical aspects, but it's rather confined to some common structures.  @Barmar

Comment: You have elided the *you realize* part, leaving the *sometime*, which goes with the missing part. *Going to have* expects *have* as a lexical verb as in *going to have a party*, so the auxiliary use is jarring. You can't use a contraction here for your negation. Thus *At some time, life will not have made sense*.

Comment: It's an excellent construction if your intention is to be self-reflexive.

Answer (score 1):

"Life is going to haven't had sense sometime", makes no sense at all.

Your second sentence: '"Sometime, there will be a moment, when you realise that life has never had any sense"' makes more sense, but is still incorrect.
The two commas are unnecessary and make the sentence sound as if it has been written by a German.

If it's American English to say something 'has' sense, then this comes straight from German, where 'etwas *hat* Sinn' ('something *has* sense'). British English would use, '*make* sense'.

If you put it in the following way: 'One day you'll look back and realise that life hasn't made any sense', it makes more sense, at least to British English ears.

Comment: Well, danke schon. Though I am not German, I'm Russian, it seems that in this case we have similar mistakes.

Comment: Also, by 'the commas are unnecessary', do you mean that I can still have them there even if that's not particularly appropriate?

Comment: Actually, it makes incredible sense, as a self-reflexive statement.

Comment: How about "Life isn't always going to make sense"?

Comment: @JSanchez: that is both grammatical and true. Its meaning, however, is completely different in meaning to that intended by the sentence in the question.